# .htaccess rewrite and hide .html extension in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I want:

```
example.com/about
```

to display the same content as:

```
example.com/about/about.html
```

so I want to hid the extension in subfolder and change how the url shows in the address bar.

How should I approach this in .htaccess?

I can make:

```
example.com/about/about
```

display the same content as:

```
example.com/about/about.html
```

but that's not what I want.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want it for this one URL and no others, you can use this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about/about.html$ /about [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't want externally redirect. I actually figure that out by only using ^about/$ as the Rewrite rule pattern